# Any example on GWT 2.1 RequestFactory with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I try to download expenses sample project but can't make it run.  I'm not familiar with maven and don't want to be confused by other new features (like mobile, activity & place...etc).
I'm not using data nucleus nor appengine.  Just want to have a bare bone RequestFactory with hibernate so that maybe I refer to it and migrate my code from Gilead to RequestFactory.  Does anyone happen to have similar kind of example?  Thanks in advance.